# Error: Failed to run custom build command for `gmp-mpfr-sys v1.4.0`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use rug, so I copied `rug = "1.11.0"` to my `Cargo.toml` file under `[dependencies]`. But I got an `error: failed to run custom build command for gmp-mpfr-sys v1.4.0`.
I do not get any errors with other dependencies, why does this error occur and how can I fix it?

I'm using Windows 10.

The entire error message:

error: failed to run custom build command for `gmp-mpfr-sys v1.4.0`

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\kimchi\OneDrive\Desktop\Rust\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-9f6df87a2d8ae0bb\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GMP_MPFR_SYS_CACHE
$ mkdir -p "C:\Users\kimchi\OneDrive\Desktop\Rust\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-dcad4e240d8aac65\out\try_external_doc"
$ cd "C:\Users\kimchi\OneDrive\Desktop\Rust\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-dcad4e240d8aac65\out\try_external_doc"
$ printf '%s' "// try_ext"... > "C:\Users\kimchi\OneDrive\Desktop\Rust\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-dcad4e240d8aac65\out\try_external_doc\try_external_doc.rs"
$ "rustc" "try_external_doc.rs" "--emit=dep-info,metadata" >& /dev/null
$ printf '%s' "#![feature"... > "C:\Users\kimchi\OneDrive\Desktop\Rust\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-dcad4e240d8aac65\out\try_external_doc\try_external_doc.rs"
$ "rustc" "try_external_doc.rs" "--emit=dep-info,metadata" >& /dev/null
$ rm -r "C:\Users\kimchi\OneDrive\Desktop\Rust\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-dcad4e240d8aac65\out\try_external_doc"
$ mkdir -p "C:\Users\kimchi\OneDrive\Desktop\Rust\lab1b\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-dcad4e240d8aac65\out\lib"
$ mkdir -p "C:\Users\kimchi\OneDrive\Desktop\Rust\target\debug\build\gmp-mpfr-sys-dcad4e240d8aac65\out\include"

--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'Windows MSVC target is not supported (linking would fail)', C:\Users\kimchi.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\gmp-mpfr-sys-1.4.0\build.rs:951:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to give full and relevant answers, please edit the question to include the complete error message. Here we can only guess at the root cause.

Comment: Crates whose name ends with `-sys` are usually Rust interfaces to libraries written in C or include a component written in C. The error you report is related to the C component, but I can't tell any more without the full error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gmp-mpfr-sys` is [not available on Windows](https://docs.rs/gmp-mpfr-sys/1.4.0/gmp_mpfr_sys/index.html#building-on-windows) when you use the default MSVC compiler backend (see `Windows MSVC target is not supported (linking would fail)` in the panic message).

You need to [install MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) first.

Then, in MSYS2 install necessary packages:

```
pacman -S pacman-mirrors
pacman -S diffutils make mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

Build your crate inside of MSYS2 environment with `cargo`.